# Why is my Stripe modal dialog window opening multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, stripe-connect

When my submit button is clicked it hides the normal submit button and the Stripe modal button is revealed. Upon hitting this stripe modal button, the stripe pay window opens allowing for the user to input payment info. For some odd reason the stripe modal window opens multiple times. This issue seems to only exist on Microsoft Edge, as it works fine on Chrome.

```
 <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-top:12px;">
            <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-left:40%;">
                <input type="hidden" name="finddriver" value="1"  />
                <input type="submit" value="<?php _e
('Submit Job'); ?>" class="normalsubmit" />
                <div class="loader"
 style="display:none;"><p>Please wait payment button is loading...</div>
                <div class="paymentbtn">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>

    $(".form-control").on("change", function(){
        var count=0;
        $(".form-control").each(function(){
            if($(this).val()){
                count = count+1;
            }
        });
        if(count >= 6){
            var pay = parseFloat($("#jobpay").val());
            payment = ("#jobpay")*100;
            $(".normalsubmit").hide();              $(".loader").show();
            $(".paymentbtn").html('<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-
key="testkey" data-image="http://icadeliveries.com/wp-
content/uploads/2016/01/Logo-final-1-e1453881025544.png" data-
name="www.icadeliveries.com" data-label="Submit Job" data-
description="Payment for this job ($'+pay+'.00)" data-amount=
("'+payment+'" />');                $(".loader").hide();
        }
            else{
            $(".normalsubmit").show();
            $(".paymentbtn").html("");              $(".loader").hide();
        }
    });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: You should really format your code.